# DM to any user on Slack using Slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to send Direct Messages (DMs) to a user on Slack using [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) using Bot token. But I'm only able to send messages to the users that are in my workspace.

How can I send message to any user on another workspaces?
When I try to do so, I get:  `"error": "channel_not_found"`

I've that user's `UserID` (`U02....`), user's email and my Bot token.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a bot/app in Slack, you grant it **OAuth Scopes** which provide the bot access to certain information in your Slack instance. So for example, I expect you have added the `users:read` Bot Token Scope to your Slack app, so that it can determine the users, and `userId`'s in your workspace.

However, this scope restricts the bot to **only see users in your workspace**.

There's a couple of ways around this though:

### **Solution 1 - Slack Connect**

Now in Slack, you can message users in other workspaces with a feature called [Slack Connect](https://api.slack.com/apis/channels-between-orgs#about).

You'll first need to establish a connection with the user you want the bot to message. This can be arranged via an invite process, and once completed that `userId` should become available to the bot. You can use that `userId` in the `channel` field of the `chat.postMessage` API to direct message the user from the other workspace.

### **Solution 2 - Org Level App**

If you are on an Enterprise version of Slack, you should have multiple workspaces *within* a company, that are all linked by an `enterpriseId`.

In this case, a possible solution might be to create what is known as an `Org Level App` to have access to information across multiple workspaces. More information on Org Level apps can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/enterprise/apps/prereqs).

Comment: Okay. I already went over these solutions. In the first approach, after sending slack connect invite, second user has to accept the invite manually from his slack account and I don't want this. In my project, what I want is if someone tags a user in comment, that user should get the comment on slack as well. That means alot of users will be tagging alot of other users. Handling slack connect for all will not be suitable.
For the second approach, as I mentioned, the user who's taging another must also have a slack account. It's not possible for all to have Enterprise version of Slack.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to @ mention/tag a user in Slack if they are not a member/guest of a workspace first. It's possible to @ mention/tag an invited user (as explained [here](https://slack.com/intl/en-ca/help/articles/360024686174-Invited-members-in-Slack)) but it's not possible to programmatically invite a user to Slack unless you are on the Slack Enterprise version.

Without knowing more about your use case, I'm not entirely sure a Slack app is the right solution to your use case here.